# Import all function in multiple module

Tags: python, python-import

I would like to import all functions in multiple modules.

This is my structure :

```
global/
  __init__.py
  test/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
```

I created :

```
test/__init__.py

from .a import *
from .b import *
```

and,

```
global/__init__.py
from .test import *
```

it's work I can call alls function from all module. But, I would like to have just one line to import directly all functions in all modules and not call module by module.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

`app.py`:

```py
from test.a import *
from test.b import *

foo()
bar()
```

You can now specify as many as functions in your `a.py` and `b.py` modules, without actually calling the prefix module.

`test/a.py`:

```py
def foo():
    print('foo')
```

`test/b.py`:

```py
def bar():
    print('bar')
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: I don't think `__all__` is needed here, the use of `__all__` is to specify a list of objects which you want to be imported with `*` which is all objects except the one's starting with `_`, the use of `__all__` in your answer is redundant.

Comment: I thought you are asking for a single-line script to import different modules. Try to clarify your question a little bit for better reach, it's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Hello, Yes my question is not very clear. I would like call directly for example foo() and bar() without call the module a.foo(). Because i can have a lot of module in test/ and ifi add a module in test/ i would like import automaticly all functions in all modules in this folder. I don't want to specify the name of module to import.

Comment: I submitted a new answer. check it out, and upvote if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Please don't submit new answers, edit the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much doable but is not recommended due to namespace conflicts in case where there might be a function defined with same name in two different modules.

But anyways for your case here is the directory structure and `__init__.py`

```
tree foo 
foo
├── __init__.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── baz.py
```

test/**init**.py

```
from .baz import *
```

test/baz.py

```
def hello():
    return "Hello World"
```

foo/**init**.py

```
from .test import *


>>> from foo import *
>>> hello()
'Hello World'
>>>
```